# What’s a good adjective for hyper-attentive-to-detail?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I’m trying to capture the following sense:

- **Primary meaning:** hyper-attentive to detail
- **Secondary considerations:**

  - no negative connotation indicating insincerity such as “pedantic”, “stilted”, or “bookish” (i.e., *not* obsessing over details in an ostentatious way)
  - it’s ok to imply that the person being labeled as this is a perfectionist, but not in a negative or excessive way (i.e, *not* “nitpicky,” “hairsplitting,” “anal”, “persnickety”, or “doctrinaire”)
  - this person cannot “shut it off” and stop being attentive to detail no matter how tired / if on vacation / wanting to “tune out”—s/he can’t help but notice minor details, even when s/he isn’t even trying to pay attention

Potential candidates (but let me know if these carry any negative connotation):

- fastidious
- meticulous

Example sentences (I’m no author; I’m just trying to give descriptive sentences with context, even at the expense of making run-ons):

- The ____________ attorney immediately spotted numerous stylistic inconsistencies in the contract (as typical of documents with multiple authors), but thought it best only to voice his concern with a substantive grammatical error that resulted in a legally ambiguous clause.
- She couldn’t help but notice his pallor, the tiny crumb on his shirt, a slight blue stain on his fingers, and the empty muffin wrapper in the adjacent garbage can. *He never eats breakfast.* His unusually-laconic reply to her question gave her pause. *Now isn’t the time to ask him this*, she thought to herself. Her ________ observations enabled her to deduce that she would fare better later on—after his blood sugar level increased.

Comment: My preference would be **meticulous**. (As you suggested.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Fastidious
```

It came to my mind as soon as I read the first line of your question.

If you go with **meticulous**, then there is another word which is very similar: **assiduous**.

Answer (score 1):

*astute* might be the word you're looking for

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astute)

> having or showing shrewdness and an ability to notice and understand things clearly : mentally sharp or clever

Answer (score 0):

What immediately came to mind was "**focused**."

"Able to direct great attention, interest, or activity towards a particular aim."

I find the word suggests a willful and non-threatening involvement.
It's a no-frills word with some character and implied integrity.