# What do you call it when someone demands too many citations?

Tags: phrase-requests

There's a debate tactic where one side repeats "you need citations" for even the most basic facts. What's a way to describe this behavior?

Comment: Maybe just ***sceptical***? Presumably the reason someone would ask for "citations" is *because they don't believe you*. But they *would* perhaps be prepared to believe what you're saying if you could cite authoritative sources to back it up. Of course, maybe the person saying you need citations is just looking for any excuse to reject your arguments - perhaps they're just ***nit-picking***.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have much time for *You need citations* in a formal debate context. Anyone who adopts that position is likely to start attacking the credibility of your references, rather than dealing with the validity of your arguments. Effectively, it just invites "ad hominem" attacks, rather than reasoned debate.

Comment: Stalling, blocking, perhaps close to filibustering: all designed to interrupt the flow of the speaker.

Comment: I think that may fall under the umbrella of "bad faith argumentation"

Comment: @Lambie others are in [10 Bullying Debate Techniques From Ben Shapiro](https://thepowermoves.com/ben-shapiro-debate-techniques/)

Comment: "Reductio ad absurdum" or "Objection, your Honor - badgering the witness."

Comment: It's definitely a type of what is known as [trivial objections, nitpicking, or hair-splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_objections) but it's not the only type of that sort of argument. Not sure there's a more precise term for it. It's also not quite [Just Asking Questions/JAQing off](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Just_asking_questions).

Comment: What's a "citation"?

Comment: A possible way to settle the debate: supply just one citation that explains the guidelines of what needs to be cited or not. E.g., for Wikipedia, that is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Common_knowledge
If both sides agree to the same guidelines, then the debate may continue in a fair and civil way. "OK, I need a source for X, but then you also need a source for Y." Etc.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate: [What is the term for someone who is very particular about the small details?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59281/what-is-the-words-for-someone-who-is-very-particular-about-the-small-details-o/59290#59290). Pedantic, fastidious, fussy, picky, persnickety [attitude]; nitpicking ... are offered there.  Hopefully, these hypernymic terms won't be repeated in answers here. [What is a good adjective for hyper-attentive to detail?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496939/what-s-a-good-adjective-for-hyper-attentive-to-detail) adds 'over-fastidious'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, they are a **pedant**?

> NOUN
> a person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning

> pe·dan·tic
> [pɪˈdantɪk]
> ADJECTIVE
> excessively concerned with minor details or rules; overscrupulous:
> "his analyses are careful and even painstaking, but never pedantic"

Answer (score 0):

I would call that person **deficient** in what they do because of their **sceptical and overzealous** way of asking for citations for every little thing as you stated.

However, if you are planning to say that to their face, you should just say that the person is being overzealous (too devoted or excited) and absurd.